# Unable to system.string to system. guid - CSOM

Tags: web-part, javascript, jquery, client-object-model

I have a picture slideshow webpart which displays images from a particular library with a particular view. I want to change the webpart property - **view** using jquery. I have used CSOM to get the webpart property and trying to update using the following code.

```
    var guid= "11A7007D-3E7F-461D-B080-02E8C2960BE4";
   webPartProperties.set_item(viewGuid , guid);
//save web part changes
 webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
```

The code which I referred to do this is available [here](http://almondlabs.com/blog/update-web-part-properties-csom/)
I get the following error :

```
           Unable to system.string to system. guid
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SP.Guid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409577%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to represent a globally unique identifier (GUID) in JavaScript.

Example

```
var viewGuid= new SP.Guid('{11A7007D-3E7F-461D-B080-02E8C2960BE4}');

webPartProperties.set_item('ViewGuid' , viewGuid);
webPartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
```